# MQTT Mosquitto C++ not publishing data (disconnecting before)

Tags: c++, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to publish a message both using commands and coding it. With the commands it works fine, I have a Broker running and a Publisher:

`mosquitto -v`

`mosquitto_pub -d -t testTopic -m "Hello"`

Then, on the Broker I get a nice response and can read the data in a subscriber correctly:

```
1642677548: New connection from ::1:60619 on port 1883.
1642677548: New client connected from ::1:60619 as auto-49A467C1-9AB0-9F4D-FEBD-6C99AB992163 (p2, c1, k60).
1642677548: No will message specified.
1642677548: Sending CONNACK to auto-49A467C1-9AB0-9F4D-FEBD-6C99AB992163 (0, 0)
1642677548: Received PUBLISH from auto-49A467C1-9AB0-9F4D-FEBD-6C99AB992163 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'testTopic', ... (5 bytes))
1642677548: Received DISCONNECT from auto-49A467C1-9AB0-9F4D-FEBD-6C99AB992163
1642677548: Client auto-49A467C1-9AB0-9F4D-FEBD-6C99AB992163 disconnected.
```

But having it in code as:

```
int main() {
    int rc;
    struct mosquitto* mosq;
    mosquitto_lib_init();

    mosq = mosquitto_new(NULL, true, NULL);

    rc = mosquitto_connect(mosq, "localhost", 1883, 60);
    if (rc != 0) {
        std::cout << "Client could not connect to broker!";
        mosquitto_destroy(mosq);
        return -1;
    }
    mosquitto_loop_start(mosq);
    mosquitto_publish(mosq, NULL, "testTopic", 6, "Hello", 0, false);

    mosquitto_disconnect(mosq);
    mosquitto_loop_stop(mosq, false);
    mosquitto_destroy(mosq);

    mosquitto_lib_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Doesn't work, it outputs in the Broker:

```
1642677347: New connection from ::1:60611 on port 1883.
1642677347: New client connected from ::1:60611 as auto-92BFFD6D-3C20-0BB1-C33D-4B251C137D04 (p2, c1, k60).
1642677347: No will message specified.
1642677347: Sending CONNACK to auto-92BFFD6D-3C20-0BB1-C33D-4B251C137D04 (0, 0)
1642677347: Client auto-92BFFD6D-3C20-0BB1-C33D-4B251C137D04 closed its connection.
```

Is there something wrong in the code or am I missing something here? (P.s. using Windows.)

Comment: You are not calling any of the client loop functions

Comment: @hardillb I've added a loop_start and loop_end between the publish+disconnect call and it still outputs the same.

Comment: Edit the code in the question to show what you've done

Comment: You probably disconnect before your `publish` was processed. You can set the publish-callback of your client and close the connection within to ensure the message got out before disconnecting. (You also need to prevent your program from terminating until published/disconnected of course)

Comment: Having got some free time, your code (as currently posted) is working for me when built with `g++ -o test_publish test_publish.cpp -lmosquitto`

Comment: @hardillb thank you for checking if it worked for you! I was compiling it directly from mcvs, however g++ is giving me error on the `-lmosquitto` (cannot find it). Hopefully I can solve this and test it.